# Jssor stacking slides on load

Tags: jquery, jssor

I've used the jssor many times and have never experienced this issue where, on load, it briefly show's both slides stacked on top of eachother (http://www.riainabox.com/).  I tried toggling the $ShowLoading variable but that didn't help.  Any ideas for workarounds?  I thought about setTimeout but since it's at the top of the page that's not really an option though if it comes down to it I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all content is overlapped in 'slides container' before initialization of jssor slider.
It looks stacked. And it will be well formatted after initialization.

Please add css 'position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;' for every slide to fix this issue manually.

```
<div class="banner1" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
```

Comment: That worked but now I'm having an issue where the second slide shows briefly on load.  I must've screwed something up.  Thanks for the response.  Love the product by the way.  Very powerful and easy to use.  This is the first time I've had an issue.

Comment: Yes, it shows brief html before initialization of jssor slider. As you use jquery version, it initializes after the whole document loaded. If you use no jquery version, it will initialize immediately with no delay. Thanks for your feedback and you are welcome!